# stl and exceptions

Tags: c++, stl

If I use reserve() to reserve enough elements for a vector, will push_back() (or insert()) throw any exceptions?

Is there a reference somewhere that specifies which stl function throw / not throw any exceptions?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to google 'c++ reference' !? Surprisingly the first result is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure this reference contains all the info I need, since I can't find any places where it guarantees a function doesn't throw. In which case, am I to assume that it means the function really doesn't throw, or that the reference simply omits that info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I use reserve() to reserve enough elements for a vector, will push_back() (or insert()) throw any exceptions?

It won't need to perform a reallocation, and so the vector *itself* won't throw any exceptions. The elements you're inserting might throw exceptions when being copied into the vector, though, so `push_back` and `insert` can still throw exceptions.

> Is there a reference somewhere that specifies which stl function throw / not throw any exceptions?

Yes, the C++ standard contains that information.

Answer (score 4):

I would say `push_back` throws when copy construction throws.

Now an exception safe implementation of `std::vector` will maintain the `vector`'s state as it was before you called `push_back` or `insert` so that you can keep using the object.

Also, have a lookt at [Lessons Learned from Specifying Exception-Safety for the C++ Standard Library](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html) by David Abrahams.

Comment: A `vector` can't really implement the strong exception guarantee. It can't roll back to the previous state because copying elements might throw, and a vector stores them by value. `vector` only provides the basic guarantee (the vector will be left in a valid state, and no resources will be leaked)

Comment: @jalf: Are you sure? I don't recall that latitude. If you add a 6th element to a vector, and it needs to reallocate, then yes the 4th copy ctor may fail. But at that point, the original array of 5 elements still exists. Rollback probably isn't even needed: you would only swap pointers after all copies succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer to the first of the two questions.

The method `reserve(K)` allocates enough space on the `vector` to accomodate `K` elements without doing a costly reallocation, but the `vector` can grow in size if enough insertions are made.